# ViewModel -> Model interaction

Tags: wpf, mvvm, model, viewmodel

Suppose I have a WPF/MVVM application for managing some hypothetical customers :).

Domain model contains an entity named Customer (represented as a POCO in code).

The main screen contains a grid, bound to a view model (CustomersViewModel) that loads its data from Repository< Customer>.

The main screen also allows to create new customers (and save it to the DB).

Suppose I need to implement 'add customer' use-case. The most obvious approach is as follows:

1. Present the user with a dialog window to be filled out with new customer data.
2. Handle 'Save' button click in the ViewModel.
3. Create customer (var new_customer = new Customer(..)) domain object using the data from the dialog (step 1).
4. Call Repository< Customer>.Save(new_customer) to save the new customer to the DB.
5. Reload CustomersViewModel with fresh data from the DB so that newly added customer is visible in the grid.

Personally I don't like this 'quick-and-dirty' way (because of need to reload the full list of customers from DB every time a new customer is added).

Can anyone suggest a better approach (that wouldn't require refreshing the customer list from the DB)???  I feel there gotta be some best practice for handling scenarios like that:) ).

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the saving of the `Customer` is successful, why can't you just add that single `Customer` instance to your collection of customers? No need to re-load all customers unless the user explicitly refreshes the view (usually via a refresh button).

Comment: That's an option I've also been thinking about. And it does avoid the need for refresh. Thanks for confirming! But in this case I'm a bit confused about where it's best to add that customer: 1. Directly to the ViewModel's collection? 2. Or to the underlying domain model (that ViewModel is listening for change notifications) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading the list in your view through a binding (to a list of customers) you can just add the new customer to that list and everything is alredy ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application where in the object is created in UI. I solve it by adding the object in VM and then syncing it with Model on click of Save button.

I am assuming you have a list of CustomerViewModel in CustomersViewModel to which the grid view is bound to. You can  add a new CustomerViewModel object to the list in CustomersViewModel. While saving the ViewModel data back into the model, the model gets in sync with VM. No need to refresh VM back from Model unless somebody else apart from your app is changing the Model data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. By 'Model' you mean the DB?

Comment: No. Model is the domain object that contains data and business logic. In this case it will be class Customer which is created by the the repository. The repository gets data from db and creates the model Customer.

Comment: Then I'd go for the following flow. When adding a customer, create new Customer domain object and fill its fields with the needed data. Then add that new customer directly to the Model. Also make sure the Model implements INotifyCallectionChanged. Then the ViewModel will be notified of any changes in the underlying model (provided VM is listening for those changes on the Model) and will have a chance to update itself accordingly.

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChange in Model defeats the purpose of MVVM. We use MVVM for loose coupling. What I mean by that is this - your Model is the actual business object which holds data and business logic. It may be a legacy object which may not be modifiable. The model is not at all aware of any ViewModel or the way it will be displayed in the View. It is only concerned with object data and behavior. ViewModel takes values from model and decides how to display it in View. So all UI logic is in ViewModel. This way all UI logic is testable in ViewModel. [to be continued in next comment]

Comment: The View binds to the ViewModel and displays data using UI controls. The View is absolutely dumb and does not take any decision. ViewModel takes all UI related decisions. Whatever changes happens in UI are reflected back into ViewModel using DataBinding. ViewModel then updates the Model which is contained in it. Tomorrow if you want to change the skin of the app, just change the View. If you want to change the way data needs to be displayed on UI, modify or replace the ViewModel. You Model in all cases remains same and changes only if there are changes in business logic.

Comment: Model is not aware of any VM of View. In fact the model may be used out of WPF app (e.g. in WinForms, or next gen UI framework) tomorrow. In that case things wil break if we implement INotifyPropertyChanged in model. Hence we should not implement INotifyPropertyChanged or do any change in Model apart from core business logic.

Comment: I'd (and I'm not the only one here - try googling on this topic) argue that implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on your Model is against MVVM purpose :). It's a common approach when you're in charge of creating your model classes. It, though, makes your model classes a bit less POCO, but it's okay for some scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an `ObservableCollection<Customer>` and fill it with the customers from the database which you want to show in the View. When you add a new customer then add it to this collection as well as save it into the database. The `CustomersView` binds on the ObservableCollection and is updated automatically without the need to refresh the data from the database.

The **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how this can be done.